# Label updates in NIB file not reflected in view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have come across this twice now while working in XCode 4, I create a new view controller add a couple of labels, add some initialisation code and find that any changes I make in the NIB file do not show up when I run the project. I had one particular case where after updating the text in the label several times and it failing to change I ended up deleting the label from the nib file and it was still displayed with the old text when I ran the application. All files were saved, I also did a clean and ran the reset option on the iphone simulator. Has anyone experienced this sort of issue before? Is the only solution to delete and recreate?

When I tried to show this file in finder it was in the .xcodeproj rather than the project folder. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: @Izac: The `UILabel` you're trying to update, are you doing that too often? i mean like a Progress Value, etc..

Comment: @AhmadTK: That has nothing to do with changes made *in IB* not showing up.

Comment: @Izac: Please edit your question to include the source for your view controller class.

Comment: “When I tried to show this file in finder it was in the .xcodeproj rather than the project folder. Why is this?” There isn't any good reason for it to be there, so you should move it out, remove it from the project in Xcode and re-add it, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I unfortunately no longer have the originals of either, due to deleting and recreating. If I come across it in future I will post.

Comment: Peter do you know what causes a file to be placed inside the .xcodeproj rather than the project folder?